# SWUpdate building error in yocto. make[1]: *** [swupdate_unstripped] Error 1 , make: *** [sub-make] Error 2

Tags: lua, yocto, bitbake, swupdate

I am building custom image in yocto and I want to include SWUpdate in my image but while building the image I am getting a build error of `make[1]: *** [swupdate_unstripped] Error 1` and `make: *** [sub-make] Error 2` below are the log messages

```
/swupdate/2021.04-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/liblua5.1.a(loadlib.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.17'

/swupdate/2021.04-r0/recipe-sysroot/lib/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

/swupdate/2021.04-r0/git/Makefile:421: recipe for target 'swupdate_unstripped' failed
```

I searched the internet about the error I am getting, and according to it if u-boot version and swupdate version are not compatible then the following error occures. But in my case both the swupdate is at its latest verson and even u-boot is at latest version.

I added meta-swupdate in bblayers.config and added swupdate, swupdate-www in IMAGE_INSTALL to add the swupdate in image.

Comment: Somewhere you lost a `-ldl` from linkage. Or it is misplaced. Bad: `gcc -o exe -ldl foo.o` good: `gcc -o exe foo.o -ldl`

Comment: actually I am new to yocto and emedded so I didn't understand your reply.Can you please make it simple to understand.

Comment: Guess you should contact your yocto/swupdate/etc provider and ask them to fix the issue.

Comment: I am the developer and want to integrate Swupdate in my image. So there is no provider

Comment: Are you referring to this product: https://github.com/sbabic/swupdate ?

Comment: swupdate 2021.04 certainly isn't the newest version -- I'm not saying it's the wrong version to use, just pointing out a possible misunderstanding. Are you sure your meta-swupdate branch is compatible with openembedded-core branch?